# datatable giving error when adding more 65 columns?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables, asp.net-ajax, datatables-1.10

I am using datatable in my mvc asp.net application, when I am working with 65 columns it is working perfectly but when I add one more column it is giving me errors i.e. **DataTables warning: table id=userTrackingList_table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7.** On console the error message is: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).**

my datatable code:
`
function GetUserTrackingListRecords() {

```
        userTracking = $('#userTrackingList_table').on('error.dt', function (e, settings, techNote, message) {
            console.log('An error has been reported by DataTables: ', message);
            console.log(e);
            console.log(settings);
            console.log(techNote);
            //HideMainDivOnLoggedOut();
        }).DataTable({

            "serverSide": true,
            "processing": true,
            "bPaginate": true,
            scrollY: "300px",
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
       
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/Dashboards/GetUserTrackingData',
                "dataSrc": function (json) {
                    userTrackingData = json.data;
                    return json.data;
                },
                "data": function (d) {
                    return $.extend({}, d, {
                        //companyCsv: Companies,
                        userId: $("#ddlUser").val(),
                        FromDate: $("#from_date").val(),
                        ToDate: $("#to_date").val()
                    });
                }
            },
     
            "error": function (e) {
                $("body,html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                showMessage(" " + e, "danger", "", "divMessage", true);
            },
            "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'B>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
            "columns": [

                { "title": "Id", "data": "id", "searchable": true, "visible": false, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "From", "data": "from", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "To", "data": "to", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Deleted", "data": "is_deleted", "searchable": false, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "User Name", "data": "username", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Password", "data": "password", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Company Name", "data": "company_name", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Branch Name", "data": "branch_name", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Customer Level", "data": "customer_level", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Level Name", "data": "level_name", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "City Name", "data": "city_name", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "CC Email", "data": "cc_email", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "POC Name", "data": "poc_name", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "POC Mobile", "data": "poc_mobile", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "POC Email", "data": "poc_email", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Salt Key", "data": "saltkey", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Hashing Data Pattern", "data": "hashing_data_pattern", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Hashing Data Pattern Description", "data": "hashing_data_pattern_description", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Master_merchant", "data": "is_master_merchant", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Random Key", "data": "random_key", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Nift Sub Merchant Id", "data": "nift_sub_merchant_id", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Nift Sub Merchant Password", "data": "nift_sub_merchant_password", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Alert Period Before Due Date", "data": "alert_period_before_due_date", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Alert Period Order Paid Summary", "data": "alert_period_order_paid_summary", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "CSV Alert Period Days", "data": "csv_alert_period_days", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Failed Login Attempts", "data": "failed_login_attempts", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Last Failed Login", "data": "last_failed_login", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Block Days", "data": "block_days", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Penalty Type", "data": "penalty_type", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Upload Image Api Access Key", "data": "upload_image_api_access_key", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Threshold Value", "data": "threshold_value", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Number Of Partial Payments", "data": "number_of_partial_payments", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Due Dates Difference", "data": "due_dates_difference", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Email Feature", "data": "email_feature", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Sms Feature", "data": "sms_feature", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Sms Paid Order Alert Template", "data": "sms_paid_order_alert_template", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Email Subject Add Order Alert Template For Consumer Code", "data": "email_subject_add_order_alert_template_for_consumer_code", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Email Subject Add Order Alert Template For Connectpay Code", "data": "email_subject_add_order_alert_template_for_connectpay_code", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Sms Paid Order Alert To Merchant Template", "data": "sms_paid_order_alert_to_merchant_template", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Emailbody Add Order Alert Template For Connectpaycode", "data": "emailbody_add_order_alert_template_for_connectpay_code", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Sms Add Order Alert Template For Connectpay Code", "data": "sms_add_order_alert_template_for_connectpay_code", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Decimal Allowed", "data": "is_decimal_allowed", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Emailbody Alert Before Duedate Template For Consumercode", "data": "emailbody_alert_before_duedate_template_for_consumercode", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Emailbody Paid Order Alert Template To Merchant", "data": "emailbody_paid_order_alert_template_to_merchant", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Emailbody Paid Order Alert Template", "data": "emailbody_paid_order_alert_template", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Emailbody Add Order Alert Template For Consumercode", "data": "emailbody_add_order_alert_template_for_consumer_code", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Sms Content Alert Before Duedate Template For Connectpaycode", "data": "sms_content_alert_before_duedate_template_for_connectpaycode", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Sms Content Alert Before Duedate Template For Consumercode", "data": "sms_content_alert_before_duedate_template_for_consumercode", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Email Subject Alert Before Duedate Template", "data": "email_subject_alert_before_duedate_template", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Paid Email Alert To Merchant", "data": "is_paid_email_alert_to_merchant", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Paid Sms Alert To Merchant", "data": "is_paid_sms_alert_to_merchant", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Send Alert Before Duedate", "data": "send_alert_before_due_date", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Emailbody Alert Before Duedate Template For Connectpaycode", "data": "emailbody_alert_before_duedate_template_for_connectpaycode", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Sms Add Order Alert Template For Consumer Code", "data": "sms_add_order_alert_template_for_consumer_code", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Email Subject Paid Order Alert Template", "data": "email_subject_paid_order_alert_template", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Email Subject Paid Order Alert Template To Merchant", "data": "email_subject_paid_order_alert_template_to_merchant", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Blocked", "data": "is_blocked", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Logged in", "data": "is_logged_in", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Verified", "data": "is_verified", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Locked", "data": "is_locked", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Partial Payment Allowed", "data": "is_partial_payment_allowed", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Transaction By", "data": "transaction_by", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "IP Address", "data": "ip_address", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Order Image Required", "data": "is_order_image_required", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Penalty", "data": "is_penalty", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },
                { "title": "Self SignUp", "data": "is_selfSignUp", "searchable": true, "visible": true, "orderable": false },



            ],
           
            rowId: 'id',
            order: [[1, 'desc']],
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
            buttons: [
                //{ extend: 'copy' },
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    title: 'CompanyLogs' + new Date().getTime() + '',
                    //exportOptions: {
                    //    columns: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
                    //}
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    title: 'CompanyLogs' + new Date().getTime() + '',
                    //exportOptions: {
                    //    columns: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
                    //}
                }
            ]
        });

    }`
```

and calling area of this function is

```
 if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#userTrackingList_table")) {
            userTracking.draw();
        }
        else {
            GetUserTrackingListRecords();
            //   setTimeout(ChildTableInquiry(), 6000);
        }
```

as you see I have added 65 columns as I add 1 more column here it will give errors. I have checked my backend is perfectly fine, only when number of columns are increased it throws above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made mistake in my ajax part, by adding **"type" : "POST"** the code will run fine.
As **"type"** of ajax request is not defined by default **"GET"** request was working, and get request was rejecting by server.